# Return the latest date per common group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005/2008 and this query:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @Todate DATETIME

SET @FromDate = '1/1/2012'
SET @Todate = '1/1/2013'

SELECT
    CASE WHEN (GROUPING(s.storeid)=1) THEN 'Total' ELSE s.storeid END AS Store,
    CAST(SUM(p.amount) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS Paid,
    CAST((SELECT 
            TOP 1 s.TRSDate 
        FROM 
            RPTrs s, 
            rpPay p 
        WHERE 
            s.StoreID = p.StoreID AND 
            s.ReceiptNO = p.ReceiptNo 
        ORDER BY 
            s.TRSDate DESC) AS DATETIME) AS LastTransaction
FROM 
    rptrs s, rppay p
WHERE 
    s.ReceiptNO = p.ReceiptNo AND 
    s.StoreID = p.StoreID AND 
    s.TRSDate >= @FromDate AND 
    s.TRSDate <= @Todate
GROUP BY 
    s.StoreID
WITH ROLLUP
```

I get this output:

[image]

It adds the correct date for the Store 01 but not Store 02 and I would like the Total line to have nothing in it.

Expected Result :

```
  | Store | Paid     | LastTransaction
-----------------------------------------------
1 | 01    | 59490.05 | 2013-03-06 00:00:00.000
2 | 02    | 238.15   | 2012-12-03 00:00:00.000
3 | Total | 59728.20 |
```

Situation. This query returns the total amount per store and the total. Along with that, what I need to add in now is the last transaction that has happened in the displayed Store. Since the date range is between 1/1/2012 and 1/1/2013, the last transaction that has happened in Store 2 is the one in the expected result. Store 1 made their last transaction at another time.

First Table is RPTrs and the Second one is rpPay

[image]

Question - How do I get the expected result?

Comment: If your range is from 1/1/2012 -> 1/1/2013, why is March 6 (or is that June 3?) 2013 coming back in the result? Wouldn't you only expect data from 2012?

Comment: Also if you show some sample data so we know how these results are derived, it may give us enough information to write a better query. It's tough to solve for this where we know what you tried, what you got, but not where it came from.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Check the updated text before "Question"

Comment: @AaronBertrand - updated post with sample data from the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer that has worked for me:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @Todate DATETIME

SET @FromDate = '1/1/2012'
SET @Todate = '1/1/2013'

SELECT
    CASE WHEN (GROUPING(s.storeid)=1) THEN 'Total' ELSE s.storeid END AS Store,
    CAST(SUM(p.amount) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS Paid,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),(CASE WHEN (GROUPING(s.StoreID)=1) THEN null ELSE CAST(MAX(s.TRSDate) AS DATETIME) END)), '')AS LastTransaction
FROM 
    rptrs s, rppay p
WHERE 
    s.ReceiptNO = p.ReceiptNo AND 
    s.StoreID = p.StoreID 
GROUP BY 
    s.StoreID
WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

> Based on the sample you provided. Try this. You need to modify it a bit based on your requirements and data.

```
SELECT R.StoreID, 
       CAST(SUM(p.amount) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS Paid,
       MAX(TRSDate)
FROM RPTrs R
INNER JOIN rpPay p ON R.StoreID = P.StoreID
GROUP BY R.StoreID
```

> [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0bfc/14)

Comment: exact same result as I had

Comment: it will be helpful if you can post some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do solve one and half part of my problem.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @Todate DATETIME

SET @FromDate = '1/1/2012'
SET @Todate = '1/1/2013'

SELECT
    CASE WHEN (GROUPING(s.storeid)=1) THEN 'Total' ELSE s.storeid END AS Store,
    CAST(SUM(p.amount) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS Paid,
    CASE WHEN (GROUPING(s.StoreID)=1) THEN null ELSE CAST(MAX(s.TRSDate) AS DATETIME) END AS LastTransaction
FROM 
    rptrs s, rppay p
WHERE 
    s.ReceiptNO = p.ReceiptNo AND 
    s.StoreID = p.StoreID AND 
    s.TRSDate >= @FromDate AND 
    s.TRSDate <= @Todate
GROUP BY 
    s.StoreID
WITH ROLLUP
```

Which gives :

[image]

Now, how do I display the `NULL` which is `DATETIME` as a blank space?

Comment: put '' instead of null on your case when statement

Comment: Tried, that returns `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: ISNULL(CASE WHEN (GROUPING(s.StoreID)=1) THEN null ELSE CAST(MAX(s.TRSDate) AS DATETIME) END, '') AS LastTransaction

Comment: Still returns `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

And your other answer is fine, just it has to have the total to it with blank date